# Handle the switch cases in another activity

Tags: android, switch-statement

I am using the switch case in my activity. I am using 6 cases they open the same activity Map.java.
Now in Map.java i want to get that from which button this activity open and want to perform toast there.
Please give me the way. thanx in advance.
here is my code

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageButton1:
        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Report.this, Map.class));
            }
        });
        break;

    case R.id.imageButton2:
        img4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Report.this, Map.class));
            }
        });
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton3:

        img5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Report.this, Map.class));
            }
        });
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton4:
        img6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Report.this, Map.class));
            }
        });
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton5:
        img7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Report.this, Map.class));
            }
        });
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton6:
        img8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Report.this, Map.class));
            }
        });
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use putExtra?

Comment: sir please give me some code that i can use for it.pleae

Comment: sir i need 1 more help. now in Map.java i want to use switch case id in if else. please give me a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a bundle and pass the parameter to the second activity:

```
public void buttonClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Report.this, Map.class);
    intent.putExtra("button", v.getId());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the second activity:

```
public class Map extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int caller = getIntent().getIntExtra("button", 0); 
        switch (caller) {
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton3:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton4:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton5:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton6:
            //do something
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Don't write redundant code, Instead define a common click listener class and assigned the same to every buttons.
2. Put Button name in intent by using `putExtra()` method of Intent.

For example (2nd step):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Report.this, Map.class);
intent.putExtra("WhichButton", "ButtonName");
startActivity();
```